# std::unique_ptr usage

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p1(new int);
std::unique_ptr<int> p2(new int);
p2=p1;
```

It seems here that p1 is no longer "unique" since p2 refer to it also

It is legal c++ ? 
Does unique_ptr have copy_semantics ? 
If no, and if it has only move semantics, is p1 set to NULL after assign it to p2 ?

**EDIT:**

ok so the correct version is

```
 p2=std::move(p1)
```

According to that, after this assign, p1 is not valid ? And the difference with auto_ptr is here? it is more safe to explictly specfiy transfer of ownership than implicitly as it is the case with auto_ptr I guess

Comment: @Andres:  As someone who has found dozens of bugs in various C++ compilers, I'd argue that is not at all true, especially when it comes to relatively new (and relatively untested) language features like rvalue references.

Comment: @James This one works, though. :)

Comment: You can have a look [here](http://wp.me/p2Bia3-2U) for typical usage of unique_ptr

Comment: p1 is holding a null pointer after 'p2 = std::move(p1);'

Answer (score 67, accepted):

std::unique_ptr is non-assignable and non-copyable.  You need to use std::move();

so

```
p1 = std::move(p2);
```

Have a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160329143115/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=400) for more info.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: broken link, can't access

Answer (score 12):

Here is an article I wrote which answers your questions.  I originally wrote this article to present an emulation of unique_ptr.  However you can ignore the first few paragraphs dealing with the emulation and just start reading at "Basic Examples".

http://howardhinnant.github.io/unique_ptr03.html

**Edit:**

I had trouble distilling the above linked article down to something small enough to make a practical answer in this format.  However here is my best shot:

> The reason: Safety in generic code.
>   One can not really make copies of
>   either `auto_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.
>   Consider:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> void foo(T t)
> {
>     T copy_of_t = t;  // line 4
>     assert(copy_of_t == t);
> }
> ```
>
> It is not unusual at all for generic
>   code to look like `foo` above. The
>   `assert` is probably not actually
>   there, but the assumption that the
>   `assert` would hold often is there ...
>   *implicitly*. Indeed, a popular implementation of `std::sort` had
>   exactly this logic in 1996, which is
>   exactly what prompted the second
>   `auto_ptr` redesign (which helped, but
>   didn't completely fix the problem).

Comment: Thanks for the article :) It is considered good practice on SO to sum up the content of the link though, so that the answer does not lose its value if the link goes dead.

Answer (score 3):

As per [this](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=400), `p2=p1` is a compilation error.