# Doing std::move twice with the same unique_ptr

Tags: c++, move, unique-ptr

What would happen if I called std::move twice with the same unique_ptr ?

```
unique_ptr<int> foo(new int(5));
unique_ptr<int> bar = move(foo);
unique_ptr<int> baz = move(foo);
```

PS: No, [std::unique_ptr usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622764/stdunique-ptr-usage) is NOT the same question. Both questions are about unique_ptr, and this is the only common thing between them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially, nothing.  The standard library requires that moving a library type leaves it in a valid but unspecified state.  By valid they mean you can still do things to the object that don't require a precondition.  That would be things like assigning it a new value or destroying it.  For `unique_ptr` we actually get more of a guarantee of the state as the [move constructor guarantees that the moved from object is set to `nullptr`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unique.ptr#single.ctor-18).  That means in the end of all of this `bar` holds the pointer and `foo` and `baz` are both `nullptr`.

Answer (score 14):

Moving from a `unique_ptr` leaves it as null. So `baz` will end up being null too.